# Error when requesting discovery dock ( HTTPS required)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, dotnet-httpclient

I am using Identity server 4. It was working fine in fact still, everything is working.  However when I try to  call

```
var client = new HttpClient();
// discover endpoints from metadata
var disco = client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(IDPBaseURL).Result;
it gives me error         
http://xxx.x.x.xx:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration: HTTPS required.
```

It's working from Visual studio and local IIS deployment. However i am facing this error only when deploying on the server.

any Idea?

Answer (score 41):

I ran into this same issue and solved it by changing the policy on the discovery document request.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest {
    Address = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx",
    Policy =
    {
        RequireHttps = false
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I am working through the IdentityServer4 quickstarts and got stuck on this.

Comment: Yes exactly, me too.

Comment: debugging runtime/production Issues in IdentityServer is tough.

Answer (score -1):

> http://xxx.x.x.xx:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration: HTTPS required.

as the error states make sure that `IDPBaseURL` is set to Https.

example

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://xxx.x.x.xx").Result;
```

Comment: Make sure your identity server is set to run on https can you navigate to https://xxx.x.x.xx

Comment: I tried it and after that im getting below error:

Error connecting to https://168.1.6.24:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

Inner Exception:  The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

https://168.1.6.24:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration is accessible in browser.